# Have an image on the left, text on the right, above and below

Tags: graphics, minipage

A while ago I have written a short text that contained this sort of template:

[image]

I am now trying to reproduce this, since I no longer have access to that LaTeX. Have tried with minipages and classic image code, but to no avail.

How could I reproduce this? A short paragraph should be placed on the right, the image on the left with a small caption (ideally with the Figure 1.1 numbering) and continuing the text below.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code below more or less reproduces what you want to accomplish

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % Dummy text


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=c]{example-image}
        \caption*{Caption of the image.}   % Remove star for a regular caption
        %\label{fig:my_label}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
        \kant[1][1-2]
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I don't see a regular caption in your screenshot. Therefore, I used a starred version. If you want the regular caption with a label, such as "Figure 1. Caption of the image", remove the star and also uncomnent the following line

```
%\label{fig:my_label}
```

in order refer refer to the image in text with `\ref{fig:my_label}`.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks a lot.